# Angular2 custom header not setting properly

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-services, angular-http

angular2 headers not setting up properly

in  **reaction.service.ts** file I have tried setup `X-Comma-Sep-Arrays: true` header. If i check in the devTools in chrome I am seeing `Access-Control-Request-Headers:x-comma-sep-arrays` and `Accept:*/*`.  [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YB4M2.png).

In console i am getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDUcv.png) error as well

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()

export class ReactionService {
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getReaction(ruid) {
        const headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
        headers.append('X-Comma-Sep-Arrays', 'true' );

        const body = 'ruid=' + ruid;
        const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true });
        return this.http.post('https://serverURL', body, options).map(
            (response: Response) => {
                const data = response.json();
                console.log(data);
                 return data;
            }
        ).catch(
            (error: Response) => {
                console.log(error);
                return Observable.throw(error);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Off point but I recommend you use [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) as `Http` is depricated and will be phased out (*not sure in what version*).

Comment: The browser recognizes a CORS situation and makes a preflight request to the server and expects a response with certain headers set. If the response doesn't contain these headers, the actual request won't be sent by the browser. Setting the headers on the client won't have any effect.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer  If take this header out `headers.append('X-Comma-Sep-Arrays', 'true' );`   it's working fine. Just for FYI  this is  `curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --header "Accept: application/json" --header "X-Comma-Sep-Arrays: true" -d "ruid=8646f3edda064e1b9788c7a90e4d30d3%2C7d921299e6a642b9896b34abecf7c87f" "http://something:9200/DynamicWebServices/rest/rxndb/GetInfoFromRuid"` my actual curl request i need to transform in to http request. 

[trnasfor curl js http request] (https://curl.trillworks.com/#node)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer

How can i know server expects with certain headers? Can you please guide me

Comment: The browser expects certain headers, not the server. The browser tells you what headers it expects. A CORS situation is when the code in the browser tries to access a server that is different than where the code was loaded from (different url and also only different port on the same server) You need to configure the server to return the expected headers.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer  I  should setup CORS situation on server side ? right

but the thing was if take the `X-Comma-Sep-Arrays: true` this out I am getting the response and everything working great.

Comment: If you don't pass custom headers, then it seems the browser doesn't consider it to be a CORS situation and immediately sends the actual request. The server needs to respond with the header mentioned in https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDUcv.png to make it work.